# How to copy every line of text on a text file with Automator on OSX?

Tags: macos, text, applescript, clipboard, automator

The deal is this:

I use http://www.clipmenu.com/ ClipMenu to have 20 states of the clipboard, because i need to copy each line of some txt file separated. So i open the txt file, and i go through every line hitting <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> then <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>↑</kbd> and so on until i reach the top and i have all the lines copied and stored in the history of ClipMenu.

My question is, is there a way to make a service or script that copies every single line in an automated way? i think i could make a script that repeat those keystrokes until it reaches the top of the txt file but i have no idea how to make it so.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do this using Automator, but using mono [MonoMac] it is very simple:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream("path", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read)) {
    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file)) {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
            String line = reader.ReadLine ();
            System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set fileText to read (choose file) as «class utf8»

set filePara to paragraphs of fileText
repeat with aPara in filePara
    set aPara to contents of aPara
    if aPara ≠ "" then set the clipboard to aPara
    end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

ClipMenu seems to ignore "transient" clipboards, so you also need a delay between the copy actions:

```
read POSIX file "/Users/username/Documents/test.txt" as «class utf8»
repeat with p in reverse of paragraphs of result
    if contents of p is not "" then set the clipboard to contents of p
    delay 1
end repeat
```

Or using UI scripting:

```
delay 1
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    set n to number of paragraphs of document 1
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    key code {125, 123} using command down
    repeat n times
        key code 124 using {shift down, command down}
        keystroke "c" using command down
        key code 126
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

The key codes are listed in Events.h.

Comment: Then second one worked, but the number of lines on each text file varies. Can i set the repeat to repeat until it reaches the first line? thanks.

Comment: I edited the answer. The first script also works for me, but did you specify the path correctly?

Comment: Now it works, but it doesn't copy the first line. How can i fix that?. Thanks.

Comment: The second script is meant to be used with files that don't end with an empty line. You could add `set n to n + 1` though.

Comment: The files does not end with an empty line, is just the first line (which has text) that doesn't get copied. I'm gonna try with n + 1 though, thanks.